# local build successful while CircleCI build failing

Tags: go, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am trying to experiment a bit with imports and now stuck on the station where simple import of package is failing in CircleCI *while it is buildable locally successfully*. Could anybody please share what is wrong or what I am doing wrong that is not letting code to be built in CircleCI?

Repo structure:

```
    - project
    --- main.go
    --- graphic
    ----- graphics.go
```

main.go import definition:

```
    package main

    import (
        "bufio"
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "os"
        "strings"

        graphic "../project/graphic"
    )
```

graphics.go import definition:

```
    package graphic

    import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"

        "github.com/fogleman/gg"
    )
```

CircleCI config.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.9

    working_directory: /go/src/github.com/<my-account>/project
    steps:
      - checkout

      # specify any bash command here prefixed with `run: `
      # - run: go get -v -t -d ./...

      - run: 
          name: run filesystem path configuration
          command: |
            pwd
            pwd -P
            echo $GOROOT
            echo $GOPATH
            export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
            echo $GOBIN
            export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
            ls -latr $GOROOT
            ls -latr $GOPATH
            ls -latr $GOBIN
            go env
      - run:
          name: run dependecy managament
          command: |
            go get -v -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
            go get -v -u github.com/fogleman/gg
            go get -v -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
            go get -v -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session
            go get -v -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cloudwatch
      - run:
          name: run documentation
          command: |
            godoc -v -index -timestamps main
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            go vet -v ./...
      - run:
          name: run build and deploy
          command: |
            dep init
            mkdir build
            dep ensure
            go build -v -o build/main.exe main.go
      - run:
          name: run qa
          command: go test -v main.go

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./build
```

Failing error message:

```
    #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
    dep init
    mkdir build
    dep ensure
    go build -v -o build/main.exe main.go
      Using ^1.3.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/fogleman/gg
      Locking in v1.3.0 (0403632) for direct dep github.com/fogleman/gg
      Locking in master (cff245a) for transitive dep golang.org/x/image
      Using ^1.23.3 as constraint for direct dep github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
      Locking in v1.23.3 (fbdf1bd) for direct dep github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
      Locking in master (e2365df) for transitive dep github.com/golang/freetype
      Locking in  (c2b33e84) for transitive dep github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath
    graphic/graphics.go:8:2: cannot find package "_/go/src/github.com/<my-account>/project/vendor/github.com/fogleman/gg" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/_/go/src/github.com/<my-account>/project/vendor/github.com/fogleman/gg (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/_/go/src/github.com/<my-account>/project/vendor/github.com/fogleman/gg (from $GOPATH)
    Exited with code 1
```

Comment: Your main file import looks strange. Should it be something similar to 'github.com/username/graphic'?

Comment: Hmm. I think no, because it is importing local directory with .go file in the repo I am importing. Do you mean I do not need to import local .go package files or to do it differently?

Comment: Just saw you use DEP. As far as i remember for dep you have to follow Golang folder structure with GOPATH (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH) env variable set. Make sure you have it set in the docker container you run in CircleCI. Also, make sure you dont use absolute path to import packages. You either import with GOPATH taken as root or use go modules.

Comment: Hmm. So. I have this output from 'go env':
```GOBIN="/go/bin"
GOPATH="/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"```

And I use 'working_directory' attribute in CircleCI config.yml like this:
```working_directory: /go/src/github.com/<my-account>/project```

What, based on this, would working paths here? Thanks.

Comment: @ArkadyB , any ideas, mate?

Comment: So, the working directory looks ok (are they for ur CicleCI instance?). Check where is this coming from `_/go/src/github.com/user/project/vendor/github.com/fogleman/gg`? Could you also show ur circle.yml?

Comment: @ArkadyB, I updated the question with complete config.yml . Please take a look.

Comment: I am not entirely sure you need to re-export Go env vars in golang docker image, i would say Circle would already care about that for you. Also, if you use dep, you don't need to download dependencies manually with `go get`, that's why you would have Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock files. Once `dep ensure` is run for your app, it should download all required dependencies. Check this example here - https://gist.github.com/azihsoyn/7f307e39e4a493c24235367e711e3725 . In case nothin would work, try to commit vendor folder along with your project and check if Circle built succeeds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198163/discussion-between-hx-unbanned-and-arkadyb).

Comment: @ArkadyB Please check link above ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think for your case will solve if you use package manager, like DEP or other.

Comment: Thanks, Kavin, for proposed solution, but if you will check the chat, linked in the comments, you will see it does not. The issue is in the way CircleCI has built the image/container. I hope they will respond to me bugreport/support request and explain what is happening there...

Comment: i see, so this is a circle ci bug..

but sometimes it can be happend if we dont use any package mangers for manage our package..

Thanks dude..